# Create New Sheet with Name Based on Form Submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets I have a script I'm using to create a new sheet for each Google Form that is submitted. It is supposed to create a new sheet with name based on the last column, column G(which isn't a form submitted column). Then it takes the information from the last row and the heading row and copy it to the first two rows of the created sheet. It also adds formulae to cells to put the info into columns(transpose) and format it based on a created sheet.

Right now it is creating the sheet and copying the formulae and format, but not giving it the proper name or pulling the last row information.

Please help!
~Charles

I have copied the code below:

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  // onFormSubmit
  // get submitted data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(
    '...');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Responses");
  var headings = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,
sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var lastRow = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1,1,
sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var studentUsername = lastRow[0][6];
  // check if username has sheet
  if(ss.getSheetByName(studentUsername)){
    var userSheet = ss.getSheetByName(studentUsername);
    // if not make
  } else {
   var userSheet = ss.insertSheet(studentUsername);
    userSheet.getRange(1,1,1,
headings[0].length).setValues(headings);
  }
  // copy submitted data to user's sheet
  userSheet.appendRow([lastRow]);
  userSheet.appendRow(['=CONCATENATE(B6," ",B5)']);
  userSheet.appendRow(['=TRANSPOSE(B1:2)']);
  userSheet.hideRows(1,2);
  userSheet.setColumnWidth(1, 500);
  userSheet.setColumnWidth(2, 500);
  var FormatSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Format");
  var FormatRange = FormatSheet.getRange("a3:b28");
  FormatRange.copyFormatToRange(userSheet,1,3,3,28);
}
```

Comment: I think you'd be better to open this by id. `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` Won't there being times when you get form submits and the spreadsheet is not active?

Comment: I think you could use appendRow here: `userSheet.getRange(userSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,
lastRow[0].length).setValues(lastRow);`

Comment: I think maybe this `userSheet.getRange(userSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1, lastRow[0].length).setValues(lastRow);` should be this `userSheet.getRange(userSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1, lastRow.length).setValues(lastRow);`

Comment: True, I did not think about when the sheet won't be open. What would you suggest? I'm still new to coding so I appreciate the help. And I'll try the adjustments you mentioned.

Comment: Well everything can still work by opening with ID.  I don't think you can use any UI's (SpreadsheetApp.getUi()) but the spreadsheet can still be open on the server and perform everything except creating dialogs and prompts and alerts..etc.

Comment: Ok, I switched the first line to openById and got "Incorrect range width, was 7 but should be 1 (line 22, file "Code")" after changing the other line.

Comment: Okay try this:
`userSheet.getRange(userSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,
lastRow[0].length).setValues([lastRow]);`
Put brackets around lastRow in setValues()

Comment: So, I switched the end of the code to appendRow like this:
`// copy submitted data to user's sheet
  userSheet.appendRow([lastRow]);
  userSheet.appendRow(['=CONCATENATE(B6," ",B5)']);
  userSheet.appendRow(['=TRANSPOSE(B1:2)']);
  userSheet.hideRows(1,2);
  userSheet.setColumnWidth(1, 500);
  userSheet.setColumnWidth(2, 500);
  var FormatSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Format");
  var FormatRange = FormatSheet.getRange("a3:b28");
  FormatRange.copyFormatToRange(userSheet,1,3,3,28);`
But I'm still drawing blank information into the name of the sheet and second row.

Comment: Okay, can you update the copy of your code in the question so I can take a look at the whole thing again.

Comment: @Cooper Updated the code. Thanks

Comment: Done. Meaning you got it working?

Comment: Okay good.  The issue with setValues is that the array has to be a2D.  I did a video on this because I had great difficulty getting this into my head.  Your welcome to take a look if you wish.  I apologize upfront for my monotonic voice. [Here it is.](https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/javascript-array-difficulties)

Comment: @Cooper I'll give that a watch later. Now the issue seems to be with the `var lastRow` and getting the sheet name right.

Comment: I just noticed that you included your spreadsheet id in the code.  That might not be a good idea to make that public.

Comment: @Cooper I figured the last part out! And put the final code in an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With some help from the comments and playing around, i figured out the code I need. Big thanks to @Cooper!

Here it is:

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  // onFormSubmit
  // get submitted data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(
    'Sheet_ID');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Responses");
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var Col = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var headings = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,
Col).getValues();
  var lastRow = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, Col);
  var studentUsername = sheet.getRange(row, Col).getValue();
  // check if username has sheet
  if(ss.getSheetByName(studentUsername)){
    var userSheet = ss.getSheetByName(studentUsername);
    // if not make
  } else {
   var userSheet = ss.insertSheet(studentUsername);
    userSheet.getRange(1,1,1,
headings[0].length).setValues(headings);
  }
  // copy submitted data to user's sheet
  userSheet.appendRow(lastRow.getValues()[0]);
  userSheet.appendRow(['=CONCATENATE(B6," ",B5)']);
  userSheet.appendRow(['=TRANSPOSE(B1:2)']);
  userSheet.hideRows(1,2);
  userSheet.setColumnWidth(1, 500);
  userSheet.setColumnWidth(2, 500);
  var FormatSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Format");
  var FormatRange = FormatSheet.getRange("a3:b28");
  FormatRange.copyFormatToRange(userSheet,1,3,3,28);
}
```

Comment: Way to go Charles